# Linked/Related questions visibility

Tags: discussion, related-questions, linked-questions

Could we bring the Linked and Related question lists back up a bit. When I am browsing SO I am less interested in SO careers and stackexchange totally not programming related question than in those links.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Linked" questions not obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113557/linked-questions-not-obvious)

Comment: Not a dupe; this one is asking for the section to be positioned closer to the top of the page, that one wants the section to be more eye-catching.

Comment: They could alternatively be moved to the left side.