# "Linked" questions not obvious

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, linked-questions

I feel like I subconsciously ignore the "Linked" section to the right of questions.

Is it just me, or would it be a good idea if it stood out more prominently?

Comment: not just you. I agree ... I also ignore it quite often, if feels like information overload

Comment: It's hard to distinguish from the usually useless and **unrelated** "Related" section.  +1

Comment: I never noticed it, I had no idea it existed until I read this.

Comment: @Matthew I dunno, I often find 'Related' a useful provider of 'close as duplicate' candidates

Answer (score 7):

Of course you ignore it. It's in the right-hand sidebar. That's where *ads* live.

IMHO, that's just fine, most of the time - after all, if you're focusing on the main content area you'll probably see *the very same links* since that's where they come from...

I look over at the "Linked" and "Related" sections when I'm trying to track down a post and my search brings up something *similar* but not quite what I want - often enough, those two sidebar tools will lead me to it. But I wouldn't want them intruding on my view once I *have* found the page I want to read. That's the sort of dirty trick *ads* like to pull.

Comment: I don't want them *intruding* either, but it has happened more than once where I've been glad to have accidentally glanced there -- there's useful stuff there sometimes.

Comment: "Linked" also lists *incoming* links, so it's not the same as in the main content. Especially the section might lead to other questions that were closed as duplicates but still might contain useful answers.

Comment: @sth: yeah, inbound links won't necessarily appear anywhere else. But there you're back to "give me related stuff" again (or piles of questions closed as duplicates of the current one). Useful enough, but *still* not worth making it intrusive IMHO.