# Can we link questions? Like a "see also" link?

Tags: feature-request

What I mean is if a question is answered but another question arises on the same subject. Is it possible  to have something set on a question that would allow a follow up question to be displayed on the original page, as another question and not as a comment?

Comment: When a question gets closed as a duplicate, a link to the duplicate question is added by the community user. Is this not what you are refering to?

Comment: Similar. Rather than closed as a duplicate, give users the option to display " this question has been answered but subject descussion is continuing here" (link to new page)

Comment: I think when relevant users will post those links... For the system to do that automagically would be quite a large undertaking... Almost every question with a certain tag would link to all other questions with that tag (If I understood you correctly)...

Answer (score 7):

This already happens.

If you mention another question (say [Should there be a way to link questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/should-there-be-a-way-to-link-questions) at random), that other question will have a "Linked" section on the right side-bar, pointing back to here.

Nothing special needs to be done for that. If you want to post a "follow-up" question, just link to the other question in your post, the link back is automatic.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9rwO.jpg]

Comment: @gna - gahh! I was just working on that ;)

Comment: @Lix are we seeing a rise of a new FPTW (First Painter in The West) syndrome?

Comment: Oooohhh fancy freehand stuff for free! Thanks a bunch @gnat & Lix :)

Comment: @gna - no fair!  Looks to me like you have a pen tablet or Wacom of sorts... that would be cheating ;)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113557/linked-questions-not-obvious

Comment: @Lix nothing but standard Windoze PC stuff like Paint and mouse. And, well, a practice of an ex-UI-tester (with hundreds fancy bug reports I submitted) - which probably could count as cheating